# Android Map related

Tags: android

I have been trying to code for MAP activity from  http://androider.blogspot.in/2013/01/google-maps-android-api-v2-example_3.html

But, I am getting error in

```
 import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
 import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
```

Its not possibe to add above mentioned imports as well as GoogleMap Class too.
Can any one help me to get rid of this, am very new to android and learning my self.

Comment: You need to download and add the google play services library...

Comment: refer this.....http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-current-location-in-google-maps-using-api-v2-with-supportmapfragment/

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the Google Play Services library project. This you can get it from your android sdk (path : basepath+android-sdks\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject). In this project's libs folder you will get a jar file called "google-play-services.jar". Put this jar file into your project libs folder and import the google play services library project into your workspace and add it to your project (to be at safer side). I think it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class FindUsActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity {

GoogleMap find_us_map;
ImageButton btn_home;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_findus);

    SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment)   getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.activity_findus_map);
    find_us_map = fragment.getMap();
    find_us_map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.title("Town Tour");
    markerOptions.snippet("We are here");

    LatLng latlng = new LatLng(40.4230, 98.7372);

    find_us_map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng, 4));
    find_us_map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(4), 2000, null);

    markerOptions.position(latlng);
    Marker m = find_us_map.addMarker(markerOptions);
    btn_home = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.activity_findus_ibtn_home);
    btn_home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
        }
    });
}

}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/activity_findus_map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>


 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.towntour.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<permission
    android:name="com.towntour.android.maps.googlev2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission  android:name="com.temp.android.maps.googlev2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDp6PHK3NYNwS74cKGdfgdmX-xc4LuH_uM1mIo" />
```

Comment: Use This code it will proper running in my application..